# Boost MD5 support?

Tags: boost, hash, md5, checksum

Does Boost have a support for MD5 checksum calculation?

Is yes, how to you use or can you provide some tutorial?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't have. Consider using OpenSSL, Crypto++, and so on.